# como resolver importacion de excel usando laravel y mongodb

Tags: laravel, excel, mongodb, csv

tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy desarrollando una api que recibe un excel en formato csv, mapeo los datos y lo guardo en mi bd de mongodb. El desarrollo de back lo hago en laravel 7.
Las primeras pruebas funcionaron bien al abrir el excel con libreOficce en linea (al hacerlo NO me pregunto cmo queria configurar los caracteres y delimitado por.), descargarlo como csv, validar, mapear los datos y hacer el insert en la BD. El problema se presenta al NO abrir el documento, lo adjunto y lo envío a mi api y al parecer rompe. No entiendo bien el por qué. Adjunto imagenes asi me explico mejor:
en este ejemplo use postman y corte la funcion con un dd para ver los datos. como se ve, llegan los datos en un array correctamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es mi codigo:

```
 $formats = array( 'text/plain','text/csv','application/csv','text/comma-separated-values', 'text/tab-separated-values');
       
  // extension correcta      
  if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], $formats)){
        
       Excel::import(new ExpedientesImport, $request->file);
   }
```

La funcion collection recibe como parametro el import de excel. En el dd es donde corto la ejecucion porq despues me tira error.

```
public function collection(Collection $collection)
{
    
    $errors = false;
    foreach ($collection as $items => $expediente) {
        dd($expediente);
        // si es un expediente 
        if ($expediente['expediente'] && $expediente['tipo_de_tramite']){
            // consulto si existe el expediente y actualizo.
```

Al utilizar la clase import de excel deberia recibir los datos como en la primer imagen adjunta. Pero ahora recibo los datos como en esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor leer [ask] y [mcve]. Las imágenes ayudan a darse una idea, pero sin el código mínimo para tratar de reproducir el problema es poco lo que se puede hacer. Te invito a [edit] tu pregunta para que agregues lo que hace falta. Saludos

Comment: es muy probable que estes tratando de abrir el documento antes que llegue totalmente.. pero sin ver tu codigo, es imposible saber que pasa

Comment: El código en formato texto, es más fácil intentar reproducir el problema si podemos *copiar y pegar*, una imagen no permite *copiar y *pegar el código. Por favor leer [mcve]. Incluso lo poco que muestras de código en la imagen no permite reproducir el problema. Saludos

Comment: que tal si agregas 'Accept-Charset: UTF-8'

Comment: si, es un problema de caracteres. Lo q hice fue cambiar la configuracion del excel.php a utf16. Gracias !!